# Adding direct action for Google Mail (and maybe other software)?

Tags: gmail, html-email, microdata, json-ld, google-schemas

I test all the examples with this mail sender: https://putsmail.com/tests/new

I read the documentation: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/getting-started#your_first_markup

And this is what I want (for example). Normally I want a normal URL Click action. Reservation is the next level.

[image: Reservation direct action on GMail]

First test was the JSON-LD one:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context":              "http://schema.org",
      "@type":                 "EventReservation",
      "reservationNumber":     "IO12345",
      "underName": {
        "@type":               "Person",
        "name":                "John Smith"
      },
      "reservationFor": {
        "@type":               "Event",
        "name":                "Google I/O 2013",
        "startDate":           "2013-05-15T08:30:00-08:00",
        "location": {
          "@type":             "Place",
          "name":              "Moscone Center",
          "address": {
            "@type":           "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress":   "800 Howard St.",
            "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
            "addressRegion":   "CA",
            "postalCode":      "94103",
            "addressCountry":  "US"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
    <p>
      Dear John, thanks for booking your Google I/O ticket with us.
    </p>
    <p>
      BOOKING DETAILS<br/>
      Reservation number: IO12345<br/>
      Order for: John Smith<br/>
      Event: Google I/O 2013<br/>
      Start time: May 15th 2013 8:00am PST<br/>
      Venue: Moscone Center, 800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103<br/>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then I tried to use this Microdata thing:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EventReservation">
      <meta itemprop="reservationNumber" content="IO12345"/>
      <div itemprop="underName" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="John Smith"/>
      </div>
      <div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Google I/O 2013"/>
        <time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2013-05-15T08:30:00-08:00"/>
        <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
          <meta itemprop="name" content="Moscone Center"/>
          <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
            <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="800 Howard St."/>
            <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="San Francisco"/>
            <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="CA"/>
            <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="94103"/>
            <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="US"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>
      Dear John, thanks for booking your Google I/O ticket with us.
    </p>
    <p>
      BOOKING DETAILS<br/>
      Reservation number: IO12345<br/>
      Order for: John Smith<br/>
      Event: Google I/O 2013<br/>
      Start time: May 15th 2013 8:00am PST<br/>
      Venue: Moscone Center, 800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103<br/>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I never see this button. In the source code of the mail I see this:

```
Delivered-To: test@example.org
Date: Sun, 06 Mar 2016 22:40:14 +0000
From: putsmail@putsmail.litmus.com
To: test@example.org
Message-ID: <56dcb1cec7e4_33fda3a013ebc7595d@4fa974b3-34c5-49ef-99b3-2597dbeeb787.mail>
Subject: test
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_56dcb1ceba24_33fda3a013ebc75828";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

----==_mimepart_56dcb1ceba24_33fda3a013ebc75828
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_56dcb1ceba24_33fda3a013ebc75828
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


<html>
  <body>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EventReservation">
      <meta itemprop="reservationNumber" content="IO12345"/>
      <meta itemprop="reservationStatus" content="Ok"/>
      <div itemprop="underName" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="John Smith"/>
      </div>
      <div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Google I/O 2013"/>
        <time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2013-05-15T08:30:00-08:00"/>
        <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
          <meta itemprop="name" content="Moscone Center"/>
          <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
            <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="800 Howard St."/>
            <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="San Francisco"/>
            <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="CA"/>
            <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="94103"/>
            <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="US"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>
      Dear John, thanks for booking your Google I/O ticket with us.
    </p>
    <p>
      BOOKING DETAILS<br/>
      Reservation number: IO12345<br/>
      Order for: John Smith<br/>
      Event: Google I/O 2013<br/>
      Start time: May 15th 2013 8:00am PST<br/>
      Venue: Moscone Center, 800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103<br/>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>

----==_mimepart_56dcb1ceba24_33fda3a013ebc75828--
```

Maybe you know how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the email from your own account or get whitelisted and authenticate the mail via DKIM or SPF. See https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know why I read how to do and then I believe that everybody can do this. I try to register my application with an example mail to the google whitelist. Thanks.